# How to convert Guitar Pro files to MIDI in batch?

Tags: midi, guitar-pro

Guitar Pro allows to export GP files to MIDI. 
But I need to convert very many GP files to MIDI.
So is there any tool to do it in batch?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** No. Guitar Pro uses a proprietary format so only Arobas Music could to that and they didn't.

**Workaround:** What you *can* do is to create a macro script (in [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com/) for example) that open the files on the desired folder for you using the Guitar Pro "open file dialog" then click the "export to midi" feature.

Comment: This is incorrect or no longer correct. Multiple tools exist to convert GP files to MIDI. The most popular solution currently is MuseScore - https://musescore.org/en/handbook/3/command-line-options#Batch_conversion_job_JSON_format

Answer (score 0):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/tuxguitar/
Tools > File format batch converter

Comment: Thanks for contributing! I can't really tell whether it's true that TuxGuitar can convert GP files to MIDI, but it seems likely. Please consider adding a bit more text to this answer, since links can go bad over time.